# Android back button and resume activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have this issue. 
I have an actvity **A** that starts other activity **B** (by onclick - button).
In **B** I have one back button to come back to activity **A**. I press it.
Now that I'm in A, I press again button to go to B.

If I use android back button (I'm in B) I come back to A first and then to B.
But now, if i press android back button again, I don't go to previus activity of A or it exit from app. I come back to B !!!

How can I prevent this behavior ?

Comment: How do you navigate from B to A? Does the button onClick in B use `startActivity()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The back button of activity B should not start activity A, but close activity B with finish:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29

Note that it is probably bad user interface design to have a "back" button on the interface. This official Android page says "Don't use labeled back buttons"
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Answer (score 0):

if you wish your custom back button to swap between the acivities A and B, you should simply launch intents, that will do.

I believe your problem is with the android back button. If you do not want go to the previous activity with this action, you can write in the manifest file under the `<activity>` tags for both A and B activities - `android:noHistory="true"`. Doing this will exit from the app. as the activity stack was storing none of the activities, but such a requirement is quite confusing UI approach.